# WordPress- Replace User Link Text

Tags: php, wordpress

While working in my project with WordPress, one issue created and I need to replace some text or domain name in URL or LINK. Like, I have link-

http://www.abcde.com

and I want to replace "abcde" text by "vwxyz" using some plugin.

Actually I have to replace only Users link text.

Is there any plugin exist that can complete my requirement ?

Comment: Why do you need a plugin? This can be accomplished by just one function call such as `str_replace("abcde", "vwxyz", $link);`

Comment: Thanks Papirtiger. But as I mentioned, I have to replace links that are related user plugin or user. Like link for edit user info or to view user profile etc. So I searching for plugin that can dynamically manage replacement of text in links.

Comment: Whats the the context? Is it for moving a site or to change urls in the text of posts? You´re pretty vague on what you´re trying to accomplish